# How write to the file continuously in Qt?

Tags: qt, qt4

I have written this piece of code as a function, each time I call this function, I want to write to the file.But this function writes only once to the file.whenever I open the file from windows I find only one word written to the file. How to write in the file continuously each time I call?

```
/* Try and open a file for output */
    QString outputFilename = "Results.txt";
    QFile outputFile(outputFilename);
    outputFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);

    /* Check it opened OK */
    if(!outputFile.isOpen()){
    qDebug() <<"- Error, unable to open" << outputFilename << "for output";
    return ;
    }

    /* Point a QTextStream object at the file */
    QTextStream outStream(&outputFile);

    /* Write the line to the file */
    outStream <<"\n"<< szTemp;//"Victory!\n";

    /* Close the file */
    outputFile.close();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the line `outputFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);` opens the file, it replaces everything that was already in the file. Try replacing the line with:

```
outputFile.open(QIODevice::Append);
```

to open it in a mode that instead appends the data to whatever exists in the file.

Note that opening the file for every single line is an inefficient solution, especially if you have many, many lines to write. Opening the file once, then writing all the words to it before closing it, would work faster.

Comment: thank you David,now that I have written 20 times to the file,now I want to overwrite from starting position of the file i.e after 20 writes i want start again from 1st.how to do it?

Comment: The same way you did originally, `QIODevice::WriteOnly`

Comment: to do this i have added the following piece of code, but what happens is at the start i get hello,then seek updates with length of sztemp,I get spaces from start till length of szTemp and then hello written in the file,each time it repeates and i get only one hello post to spaces                               outputFile.seek(seeK);
    /* Write the line to the file */
    outStream << szTemp;//"Victory!\n";
    if((++count)>=20)
    {
        outputFile.seek(0);
        count =0;
    }
    seeK +=strlen(szTemp); where seeK is static int variable